# FInding out the Harshad number

Tags: javascript

I am being stuck in situation where the problem is defined as:

> Harshad/Niven numbers are positive numbers that are divisible by the sum of their digits. All single-digit numbers are Harshad numbers.
>
> For example, 27 is a Harshad number as 2 + 7 = 9, and 9 is a divisor
>   of 27.
>
> Harshad numbers can occur in consecutive clusters. The numbers 1
>   through 10 are Harshad numbers. The numbers 132 and 133 are both
>   Harshad numbers. The numbers 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017 are Harshad
>   numbers.
>
> Create a function that takes a number and returns an array of two
>   elements. The first element is the length of the Harshad cluster of
>   which the number is a part. The second is its order in the cluster.
>
> Examples harshad(5) ➞ [10, 5] // cluster = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
>   10] // The second element should be the layman order in the //
>   cluster, not the programming index. 
>   harshad(133) ➞ [2, 2] // cluster = [132, 133]

so i have figured out a way to find out all the harshed cluster greater than the number passed as arguement to function whose code is defined below

```
function track(num) {
  let a = num.toString().split("");
  let b = a.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);
  if (num % b != 0) {return;}
  console.log(num,num%b);
  if (num % b == 0) {
    num++;
    track(num);
  }

}
track(1015);
```

> so console.log() gives me 1015,1016 and 1017

cluster as they are greater than 1015 which is passed to the function now how can i check for the numbers smaller than 1015 as 1014 should also be the answer but i just cant write another IF statement after the first IF statement and make it as

```
   function track(num) {
      let a = num.toString().split("");
      let b = a.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b, 0);
      if (num % b != 0) {return;}
      console.log(num,num%b);
      if (num % b == 0) {
        num++;
        track(num);
      }
 if(num%b==0){
        num--
        track(num)
      }


    }
    track(1015);
```

as this makes no sense

Answer (score 3):

You could separate the functions, one for checking if a number is a harshad value and another which collects these numbers by decrementing the value and incrementing and collecting valid numbers in an array.

```js
function harshad(value) {
    function isHarshad(value) {
        return value % Array.from(value.toString(), Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b) === 0;        
    }
    
    var cluster = [],
        left = value,
        right = value + 1;
        
    while (isHarshad(left)) cluster.unshift(left--);
    while (isHarshad(right)) cluster.push(right++);
    return [cluster.length, cluster.indexOf(value) + 1];
}

console.log(harshad(5));    // [10, 5] cluster = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(harshad(133));  // [ 2, 2] cluster = [132, 133]
console.log(harshad(1015)); // [ 4, 2] cluster = [1014, 1015, 1016, 1017]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function track(num) {
  const isHarshed = n => {
      let a = n.toString().split("").reduce((a, b) => (+a) + (+b), 0);
      return n % a === 0;
  };
  if (!isHarshed(num)) {return false;}
  let index = 1;
  let count = 1;
  let n = num - 1;
  while(isHarshed(n)) {
    count++;
    index++;
    n--;
  }
  n = num + 1;
  while(isHarshed(n)) {
    count++;
    n++;
  }
  return [count, index];
}
console.log(track(5));
console.log(track(133));
```